# HTML form from Google Sheet

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I an trying to make a registration form picking values from a [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13oYduqhOicLEuAJOPBnx8kymyUhz9tnBdDjubfn1ubY/edit#gid=0)

Please view the Data in the Sheet link

First question is "Course" - Drop down from A2:A of the sheet
[image]

Sample form

Select your course
______________________ (drop down from A2:A in Sheet)

If Java is selected, (Java is found in Row 4 of sheet)

next questions will be picked from B4 to F4 of sheet. All text answers.

Do you like java

---

How will you use java

---

Is java good

---

Is java famous

---

Tell me about Java

---

If App Script   is selected (it is found in Row 3 of sheet, questions will be from B3 to C3 of the sheet - only two questions - text box answers)

Why do you want apps script

---

How will you use app script

---

After completing these questions, there will be a few more questions like name, age and file upload (resume) to a google drive folder.

The response will go into a new row in another google sheet. Resume url will appear in a fixed column in the answer sheet.

The answers sheet will look like

TIMESTAMP-NAME-AGE-RESUME URL-COURSE-ANSWER1-ANSWER2-ANSWER3-ANSWER4-ANSWER5

I referred to a few helpful articles like

[Populate HTML form from Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39186400/populate-html-form-from-google-sheets)

[How to Populate HTML Service Select Options from Range in Google Sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577433/how-to-populate-html-service-select-options-from-range-in-google-sheet)

[Dependent Dropdown in HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67052620/dependent-dropdown-in-html-form)

I was able to populate the first drop down. But, I am not able to reach the next section in the same HTML form, depending on the value selected in the first question.

If the data in sheet is changed (add/delete/edit), the form must change automatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232146/dynamically-populating-drop-down-list-from-selection-of-another-drop-down-value?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your response. I edited the sheet and the question also. I provided sample form layout also. Hope it is clear.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike There is no need to apologize. The flow will be : 1.User has to select a course (this will be fetched from the sheet A2:A) , 2.Once he selects a course, a few questions will be asked about the course he has selected (this will be from the sheet corresponding to the row from Column B till Column F); 3.He has to answer the questions (maximum 5 questions), 4.Then he will be asked for his name, 5.Then he will be asked for his age, 6. Then he has to upload his resume, 7.Once he submits, all the data he entered will be stored in a different sheet in a new row

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your showing image is your input situation? If my understanding is correct, can you provide your sample output situation by using your input situation?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xAI9Od0vxvFL9Co49Z23LgUOVnFwKIZ_jFisWB_4mWw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That's the output sheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided sample output situation, you want to copy values from Spreadsheet A to Spreadsheet B. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the detailed logic for retrieving the values?

Comment: The questions are from Spreadsheet A. The answers are provided by the user. The answers (by the users) will be stored in Spreadsheet B in a new row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252075/discussion-between-arul-selvan-and-tanaike).